# How to group by and drop the last 2 rows in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

in the pandas data frame, I want to group by one column (ID) and then drop the last 2 rows for each ID.

I know this code will keep the last 2 rows for each ID, but I'm looking to drop last 2 rows and keep the rest.

```
df.groupby('ID').nth(-2)
```

Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
df.drop(df.groupby('id').tail(2).index, axis=0)
```

Can add the `inplace=True` argument, if needed.